# Accessing a variable passed by jquery using php

Tags: php, jquery

How does php access a variable passed by JQuery?

I have the following code:

```
$.post("getLatLong.php", { latitude: 500000},
   function(data){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```

but I don't understand how to access this value using php.

I've tried

```
$userLat=$_GET["latitude"];
```

and

```
$userLat=$_GET[latitude];
```

and then I try to print out the value (to check that it worked) using:

`echo $userLat;` but it does not return anything. I can't figure out how to access what is being passed to it.

Comment: `$.get(..)` > `$_GET[..]` | `$.post(..)` > `$_POST[..]` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$_GET is for url variables (?latitude=bla), what you want is ..

```
$_POST['latitude']
```

Answer (score 2):

use $_POST['latitude'] instead of $_GET.

the reason of course is that your jQuery call is to $.post, which transfers your latitude via the post method.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `$.post`. That means it will be in the $_POST superglobal in PHP.

If you were using `$.get`, it would be sent to PHP in the query string, and be in the $_GET superglobal array.

If you want to access it without worrying which HTTP method you used in jQuery, use $_REQUEST.

Try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` or `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP page, and look at the data that comes back using Firebug or the webkit Inspector.